# set up a many-to-one relationship spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, dao

im trying to learn some jsp as well as the spring framework.

My application has 2 sql tables. 'User' and 'Locations'

each Location belongs to a User. The location table has a foreign key referencing the id of the user.

I want to implement my application such that given a user (i.e 'user1') i can call user1.getLocations() to retrieve a list of the locations associated with that user, but i do not know where to implement this. (in the User class, on the UserDao, on the UserManager, on the controller for the page that should list all users and their , etc?)??

----edit:
On the controller:

```
    List<User> users = userManager.getUsers();  
    for(User user:users) {
        user.setLocations(locationManager.getLocations(user));
    }

    myModel.put("users", users);
    return new ModelAndView("location", "model", myModel);
}
```

is this a conventional solution? locationManager.getLocations(user) returns a List of Locations with the same id as user.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a conventional solution, you should only need to get the users and the location-lists should be automatically filled (if using eager-fetching or query that forces the lazy-relations to be fetched). I'd still suggest looking for more in-depth tutorials on the subject via search engines, there should be plenty floating around. I'd look up some for you, but unfortunaly I have to head for work now.

Comment: thanks, i believe i added that before i had read your original answer.

Comment: esaj, if you've got a second could you recommend a tutorial/some information? im starting to get a little overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My application has 2 sql tables.
>   'User' and 'Locations'
>
> each Location belongs to a User. The
>   location table has a foreign key
>   referencing the id of the user.
>   I want to implement my application such that given a user (i.e 'user1') i can call 
>   user1.getLocations() to retrieve a list of the locations associated with that user 
>   , but i do not know where to implement this.

I wouldn't create a separate DAO-method for handling this, the "user1.getLocations" is the right approach. Hibernate et al. support stuff like lazy-loading and mapping of table relations as Collections (like Lists and Sets) between entities, which are meant for these kind of situations. Here's a simple example,which might not work out-of-the-box, depending how your tables are named etc., but you'll get the idea:

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Location> locations;

    public List<Location> getLocations()
    {           
        return locations;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Location
{
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Note that you can get the locations from the User-side, even though the relation in the database is only from Location to User (the "mappedBy"-attribute in Users' @OneToMany actually tells which field on the "other side of the reference" (Location) points to this User).

I'd suggest looking up some JPA and/or Hibernate with Spring -tutorials for more in-depth information.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i was hoping for a solution with the user1.getLocations() approach.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely in the **UserDao** class since it sounds like a DB operation. Also the method should be more like this signature **userService.getLocations(userId)** as opposed to **user1.getLocation(), user2.getLocation().**, etc.

You can get a quick overview of the [MVC pattern](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-mvc-design-pattern-with.html), learn more about the [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) and a [tuotrial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).

You will definitely need to chain your method calls to the dao from the view. So traditionally it's done this way: a request from the view (V in MVC)->controller dispatches (C in MVC)->service class (part of M in MVC)->dao class (also part of M in MVC) and sent back to view by flipping the directions.

Comment: Okay ... let us know if you have more questions.

Comment: Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   
        
        List<User> users = userManager.getUsers();
            //CODE TO SOMEHOW RELATE LOCATION LIST WITH USER
        myModel.put("users", users);

        return new ModelAndView("location", "model", myModel);
    }   in the commented section how would i add the locations (gotten using userService.getLocations(userid)) to the model in a way such that i can tell which user they belong to on a jsp page. ideally, im trying to use nested forEach loops to display each user and their locations

Comment: You will be sending it via myModel and then use jstl to loop through the locations. In fact the location should be a field in the User class.